# How do I strip &rlm; in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have an HTML element that looks like the following:

```
<span>&rlm;3</span>
```

I set up a click event handler on this element (code not shown) that gets the `innerHTML` of this span:

```
e.currentTarget.innerHTML
"‏3"
e.currentTarget.innerHTML.length
2
e.currentTarget.innerHTML.charAt(0)
"‏"
e.currentTarget.innerHTML.charAt(1)
"3"
```

Based on the length, it seems that Javascript/Chrome is converting the `&rlm;` marker to the unicode invisible character when is displayed on the console.

When the span contains no `&rlm;` marker, things work as expected:

```
e.currentTarget.innerHTML
"3"
e.currentTarget.innerHTML.length
1
```

Any idea on how to strip this character? I've tried `.trim()` and `.replace()`.

Comment: Simple solution in my mind just to use regexp, like e.currentTarget.innerHTML.replace( /&rlm;/g, '') shold solve the problem, but maybe someone will give better suggestion :)

Comment: I just did something similar with:
e.currentTarget.innerHTML.replace(/\u200f/g, '')

Answer (score 3):

```
e.currentTarget.innerHTML.replace(/\u200f/g, '')
```

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: This is technically correct: `\u200f` is the JavaScript escape for RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (U+200F). But such marks should not be removed unless you *know* they should not be there, and then you should primarily to try fix the system that produces them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Probably it's user form submission. Somebody decided to be smart and now it has to be fixed. :P

Comment: Yes it could be from form data, either by a smart user or by smart software. So should it be stripped off (“it’s Hebrew to us, we delete it”), or should the character data processing be prepared to such data? It’s possible that the element containing this data should have `unicode-bidi: embed` to prevent the RLM from affecting *other* content.

Comment: Thanks for the note about `unicode-bidi: embed`. I will look into it further.

Comment: You saved the day. What the heck is this? It screwed up the html, but I can't see those characters in chrome debugger.